# Omit the "Name" parameter in "Display" Data annotation but use "ResourceType"

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations, resourcedictionary

I'm looking for a way to omit the `Name` attribute from the `Display` Data annotations in my MVC project but still use the resource type.

what I want to achieve by doing this is that in my resource file I got all the propertie's names and their values I want  and I expect it to "see" the current property name and look for it in the resource file.

example code:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    // this is the normal way that works
    [Display(Name = "Name", ResourceType = typeof(Titles))] 
    public string Name { get; set; }


    // this is what i want to do 
    //but it's not working (yet no compile issues)
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Titles))] 
    public string Info { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: You can't how would it know which entry in the `Resource` file to use for the property

Comment: I thought maybe theres a way to "tell it" look at the current Property's name. some sort of `this` but with the property's context of course

Comment: No not that I'm aware of and in any case what would you do if you needed to add a `Required` attribute to the same property, how would it distinguish between different types (context) of the resources being used